# Условие с true / false

Tags: javascript

Есть условие на проверку существует ли вообще поле, и если поле существует мы его обрабатываем, но столкнулся с очень удивительным результатом. В примере все поймете :)

По сути если есть `data.visible` то оно должно вернуть `VISIBLE` но так как заходит `false` он его пропускает. Кто подскажет лучшее решение для этой задачи?

```js
function result(data) {
  if (data.visible) {
    return 'VISIBLE: ' + data.visible;
  } else {
    return 'NOT VISIBLE';
  }
}

console.log('OK', result({
  visible: true
}))
console.log('OK', result({
  visible: false
}))
console.log('FAIL', result({}))
```

Comment: Нашел одно решение с typeof, есть ли еще варианты?

Comment: Какое вы поведение ожидаете, когда `visible` в `data` не существует?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, должно уйти в `else`

Comment: @Puvvl, так оно ж и так уходит в `else`

Comment: @alvoro, вы не поняли вопрос. Если есть `data.visible` оно должно уйти в `if` если же нету должно уйти в `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужен оператор [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). Также вас может заинтересовать метод [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Оператор `in` проверяет присутствует ли свойство (пускай даже его значение "falsy" (`0`, пустая строка, `undefined`, `null`, `false`)) в самом объекте или одном из его предков по цепочке прототипов. `hasOwnProperty` делает тоже самое, но не лезет в цепочку прототипов (как видно из названия).

```
function result(data) {
    // if ("visible" in data) { // если будем проверять родителей
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("visible")) {
        return 'VISIBLE: ' + data.visible;
    } else {
        return 'NOT VISIBLE';
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста.